# Azure Cosmos DB advice

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have a web application that sits in the IoT space.  We have sets of data called "data runs" and they are about 100k data points each consisting of timestamp and value. These data runs are viewed in a web portal that is hosted in azure.  The data runs are viewed in a line chart (highcharts).  Currently all the time series data is stored in SQL server hosted in Azure.  We are finding the retrievals from the database are getting slow as we have a couple hundred million records in the time series table.

I decided to look into CosmosDB in Azure and am able to get the data uploaded into documents and retrieve the data using the .NET sdk for CosmosDB.  The problem is I keep going over the allowed requests per minute to CosmosDB.  At any given time we could have a hundred or so users viewing these data runs which means a request to CosmosDB for each user.  We also allow the user to remove data points using the UI on the chart, which then means a document update to CosmosDB.  I'd like to think our app scale and the amount of users is quite small but I'm totally lost as to how to make this work without bumping up the throughput and paying $1000 month for CosmosDB.  Has anyone used CosmosDB for storing data that requires constant retrievals and updates?  Maybe I am trying to use CosmosDB for something it's not generally designed for?  Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

CosmosDB is very fast and gets very expensive if you're not careful. You'll probably have to rethink how you make your requests and either batch them up or use some type of caching to hold the changes until you want to commit.